# How do I generate embeddings for dicts (not text) for Vertex AI Search?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vector-search, google-generativeai

I am trying to generate and store vector embeddings in my GCS bucket such that they can be accessed by Vector AI Search to find the most similar items.

Following [this official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/overview), they mention that the first step is to generate an embedding, and that this can be done by [generating text embeddings](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/embeddings/get-text-embeddings).

If we look at the referenced code, with Python one would do the following:

```
from vertexai.language_models import TextEmbeddingModel


def text_embedding() -> list:
    """Text embedding with a Large Language Model."""
    model = TextEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained("textembedding-gecko@001")
    embeddings = model.get_embeddings(["What is life?"])
    for embedding in embeddings:
        vector = embedding.values
        print(f"Length of Embedding Vector: {len(vector)}")
    return vector
```

Now there is [another tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/vector-search-embeddings) where they basically generate and store vector embeddings, also using `textembedding-gecko` model from Spanner to Vector Search. Obviously, data stored in Spanner is not stored as a text and has a row/column or key/value dict structure.

With the code above, which is pointing on generating text embeddings, this format is not supported. How do I therefore go from a dict to embedding?

Other resources I looked at:

- Generating text embeddings for Stackoverflow data. Even here they don't explain how to go from column format to generate an embedding, as they only use the column "title". See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/blob/main/embeddings/intro-textemb-vectorsearch.ipynb

Other comments:

- In case of product images as the initial tutorial shows, one would indeed expect the object to have multiple attributes, not just texts.
- In the future, I would also like to explore overweighting and underweighting some attributes if possible.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How will you use the embeddings? Which questions do you want to answer? I'm asking that because the purpose of embeddings is to understand and extract the meaning of a text. A vector search engine find similarities (proximities) between embeddings. A list of column in a dict has no meaning. Do you want to compare a list of dict with another list of dict in the future?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The end goal is to query for the most similar items in a database, based on the provided input. I have not yet found how this can be achieved for tabular or dict data, as most embeddings focus on text. However, the integration of Spanner example tutorial makes me think that it is possible for tabular (row/col) data.

Comment: Format your tabular as text, and query live data as formatted in the embeddings. Something like that: `here the list of column ....`

Comment: That doesn't work well with exact matches, it somehow looses the accuracy. I have the feeling that we need to do something like one feature per column, but not sure this is supported.

Comment: Sure, 1 value per column has low "meaning" and therefore low embedding accuracy. The semantic is the key with LLM.

Answer (score 0):

Vertex AI text-embeddings API (i.e. `textembedding-gecko@003`) takes snippet of text as input and generate array of floating point numbers (embeddings). The REST API supports the following input request(SDKs are the same):

```
{
  "instances": [
    { "content": "TEXT"}
  ],
  "parameters": { 
    "autoTruncate": AUTO_TRUNCATE 
  }
}
```

So, it consumes an array of raw text. If the source of the texts are coming from a database table (as the stackoverflow example you are referring), it should create embedding instances per column (one embedding per selected row, think of a specific feature of a data instance). It should NOT take an entire row as embedding input since the embedding API will not understand the relationship of the columns. This applies to the Spanner ML.predict since it uses the same Vertex AI embedding APIs under the cover.

To your second question, I guess you refer `multiple attributes` as input with both text and images? In that case, it uses the [multimodal embeddings API](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/multimodal-embeddings) can take input object with text, image and video. They are for the purpose of multimodal instead of multiple attributes. As shown in the [multimodal embedding request](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/embeddings/get-multimodal-embeddings):

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "text": "TEXT",
      "image": {
        "bytesBase64Encoded": "B64_ENCODED_IMG"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This will send an embedding request with image and text data to `POST https://LOCATION-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/publishers/google/models/multimodalembedding@001:predict` multimodal embedding API.

Comment: I think you are on to something. How would you structure the JSON file that requires id and embedding from the docs? Or upserting datapoints? Note, I would like text for each column, multiple features per datapoint id.

Comment: don't think you can structure JSON to include the ID and embeddings. You might end up building custom wrapper application that pre-process the data, retrieve and format the Id field and extract the text for embedding. Then pass the extracted to Vertex embedding API as shown the sample JSON input. Finally, package/wrap the returned embedding into whatever data-structure you like to persist/process.